# Can we do regex for Response so that Consumer can have values dynamically?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have written regex for  response but the .json files are are creating with some wierd values like ABSGDKJEUDSGASH,
Can some help me in these

Response:
'agent': value(consumer((anyNonBlankString())), producer("abcd"))
Created Stubs
\"agent\":\"CVCHFTMETQSEOLOQENTY\":

Can spring cloud contract support response dynamically as it supports request??

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? `consumer(anyNonBlankString())` is giving you exactly what you asked for, which is a string that contains at least one character.
Spring Cloud Contract will generate a random string consisting out of 20 characters when you use that regex.

Comment: For request we are able to write consumer(matching(anyNonBlankString())),but comming to response it is not allowing to write the same .

Answer (score 2):

`consumer()` is related to stubbing, `producer()` is related to the generated test. The matching in the request part is to make sure that the incoming HTTP request on your WireMock server matches the criteria that you have specified. Now everything that you write in the response side is what WireMock will return if your HTTP request matches those criteria.

- If you need to return a fixed value, use `consumer('my agent')`.
- If it doesn't matter what you receive as a response, you can use eg. `consumer(anyNonBlankString())`.
- If you want to return the same value as what you received from the client you can do something like `consumer(fromRequest().header('agent'))`.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for quicky response, Herw is my concern In these  If you need to return a fixed value, use consumer('my agent'), i dont want to fixed response my response should take any string instead of fixed value

Comment: Your response needs to return something instead of accepting something, and that's what you define in the response part of the contract. In the answer above I summed up the 3 options which are available. Spring Cloud Contract will generate the json files for WireMock like what you can see here (http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/) and here (http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/)